# How can I adapt this javascript to return a postcode less the last 2 characters?

Tags: javascript

```
function() {
    var address =  $("#postcode").val();
    var postcode = address.split(' ');
    postcode = "Postcode:"+postcode[(postcode.length-2)];
    return postcode;
}
```

This js pulls a postcode value from an online form when the user runs a query. I need to know how I get it to deliver the postcode less the last 2 characters. for example, SP10 2RB needs to return SP102.

Comment: Please try to do your own research before posting a question. A quick search of "JS get part of string" will give you plenty of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice).

Answer (score 1):

You have to slice the string and return what you want:

```
return postcode.slice(0, -2);

// example
postcode = "sample";

// output
"samp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function postCode(address)
{
    var tmpAddr = address.replace(' ','');
  tmpAddr = tmpAddr.substr(0, tmpAddr.length-2);
  return tmpAddr;
}

alert(postCode('SP10 2RB'));
```